# Fish disappearing in small tank

Tags: aquarium, fish

I have a five-gallon freshwater fish tank with 3 guppies, 2 ghost shrimp, 7 nerite snails, 1 mystery snail, and 3 dwarf catfish. 2 catfish and 2 guppies have disappeared completely. There are 0 bodies at the bottom or floating. What could have happened?

Comment: you have an assorted collection of predators and scavengers in your tank,and your tank is way too small for the number of animals.

Comment: Welcome to Pets :) I've marked your question as a duplicate of one that has already been asked. Please check out the answers there which will answer your question :)

Comment: Do you have a cat?

Comment: What sort of substrate do you have? Plants? Ornaments? What kind of filter (with sponges or an "under gravel" filter, internal or external)? If there's nowhere for them to hide, chances are they've been eaten (and my money is on "mystery snail"!).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes small fish get sucked into the water filter and cannot escape on their own.

To prevent that, you could wrap a piece of fine tight around the suction opening of your filter, securing it tightly in place. If the fabrig gets sucked into the filter, it might block it.

Comment: I checked the filter and did not find them and I have a lid on the tank.